# Producer-Consumer Multithreading segmentation fault: core dump

Tags: c, multithreading, linked-list, queue, producer-consumer

This is the paragraph that is stated with our homework we had to do:

> The simulation will use a dedicated thread to read user requests
>   (processes) from an input source.  The request thread allocates space
>   for the request and adds it to the request queue.  The simulation also
>   has dedicated threads for handling each processor. Each processor
>   thread removes a request from the request queue and simulates running
>   the process by waiting for a specified amount of time. As the
>   processor thread simulates the execution of the process, it will log
>   the process number, the start time, and the end time to a log file.
>   When the run time is complete, the processor thread frees the request
>   and handles another request.  The threads within the simulated
>   multiprocessor computer require producer-consumer synchronization with
>   a single producer (the request thread) and multiple consumers (the
>   processor threads). The queue itself must be protected with mutexes so
>   that items are removed and added in a consistent manner. The consumers
>   must synchronize on the requests available in the queue, so that they
>   do not attempt to remove nonexistent requests. The request queue is
>   not bounded because the request thread dynamically allocates space for
>   requests as they come in.
>
> There may be several different process queues sending processes to
>   specific processors or groups of processors best suited for the
>   particular job.  Processing requests may be allowed to have priorities
>   or other characteristics that affect the way in which they were
>   printed.  This implementation keeps pending requests in a request
>   queue and threads need to be properly synchronized. You are required
>   to design and implement a proper synchronization mechanism with the
>   requirement that the queue can grow arbitrarily large.

---

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<semaphore.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<time.h>

typedef struct pr_struct
{
    int owner;
    int burst_time;
    struct pr_struct *next;

} prcmd_t;
static prcmd_t *pr_head=NULL;
static prcmd_t *pr_tail=NULL;
static int pending_request=0;
static pthread_mutex_t prmutex=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void displayQ();//this displays the queue
void initializeData();//initializes the data for the program
void *get_request(void *args);//to be calls as a thread to enqueue input requests
void *producer(void *args);//which removes a request from the process request queue and runs it
int get_number_request();//returns the number of request
int add_queue(prcmd_t *);//adds a node at the end of the request queue
int remove_queue(prcmd_t **);//removes a node for the queue


sem_t empty;//semaphores
#define EXIT 1
#define MAX_PROCS 5
#define TRUE 1

char outbaseStr [100];
int numProcessors;
FILE *outLog=NULL;
FILE *file=NULL;
FILE *outFile=NULL;
FILE *temp=NULL;
pthread_t processor;//Producer Thread ID
//pthread_t consumer[MAX_PROCS];//consumer thread ID
pthread_t consumer;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* Initialize Data */
    initializeData();

    printf("argc equals %d\n", argc);
    int num_processors=atoi(argv[1]);
    int case_num=atoi(argv[2]);

    printf("num_processors equals %d\n\n", num_processors);

    switch(case_num)
    {
    case 1:
        //printf("case 1\n");
        /* Reading in from the text  */
        file = fopen("temp.txt", "wr");

        /* fopen returns 0, the NULL pointer, on failure  */
        if(file==0||file==NULL)
        {
            printf("Error: couldn't open the file\n");
            exit(EXIT);
        }

        int num=3;
        int a;

        for(int i=num;i<argc;i++)
        {
            if(i%2==0)
            {
                a=atoi(argv[i]);
                //printf("(a)argv[%d] equals %d\n", i, a);
            }
            else
            {

                //printf("argv[%d] equals %d\n", i, atoi(argv[i]));
                fprintf(file, "%d %d\n", a, atoi(argv[i]));
            }
        }


        fclose(file);
        /* Create the producer thread  */
        pthread_create(&processor, NULL, get_request, (void *)file);

        break;
    case 2:

        //char filename[100];
        //filename=argv[3];
        printf("usage: %s filename\n", argv[3]);


        /* Reading in from the text  */
        file = fopen(argv[3], "r");

        /* fopen returns 0, the NULL pointer, on failure  */
        if(file==0||file==NULL)
        {
            printf("Error: couldn't open the file\n");
            exit(EXIT);
        }


        /* Create the producer thread  */
        pthread_create(&processor, NULL, get_request, (void *)file);

        break;
    default:
        printf("Error: should be either case 1 or case 2\n");
        exit(EXIT);
        break;
    }

    pthread_join(processor, NULL);


    displayQ();



    for(int i=0;i<num_processors;i++)
    {
        sprintf(outbaseStr, "%s.%ld", "processor.out", (long)(i+1));
        printf("outbaseStr equals %s\n", outbaseStr);
        outLog=fopen(outbaseStr, "w");
        if(outLog==NULL)
        {
            printf("Error: couldn't open the file\n");
            exit(EXIT);
        }

printf("debug\n");

//***************************************************************************************/
//THIS IS THE LINE OF CODE IM TALKING ABOUT
//***************************************************************************************/
        // Create the consumer threads
        pthread_create(&consumer, NULL, (void *)processor, (void *)outLog);
        //pthread_create(&consumer[i], NULL, (void *)processor, (void *)outLog);
    }


printf("after the for loop");

    for(int i=numProcessors-1;i==0;i++)
    {
        pthread_join(consumer[i], NULL);
    }


    fclose(file);

    //then theres a remove temp.txt
    if(remove("temp.txt")==0)
    {
        perror("error deleting the file");
        return 0;
    }




}
void initializeData()
{
    printf("initializeData\n");
    //Create the empty semaphore and initialize it
    sem_init(&empty, 0, MAX_PROCS);

//  pthread_attr_init(attr);
}
void *get_request(void *argv)//this produces a queue
{
    printf("get_request\n");

    prcmd_t *process;

    while(!feof(file))//if num=0 that means there are no queues and if it is zero you can't consume 0 queues
    {
        process=(prcmd_t *)malloc(sizeof(prcmd_t));
        fscanf(file, "%d %d", &process->owner, &process->burst_time);

        add_queue(process);

        int num=get_number_request();
        printf("num equals %d\n\n", num);
    };



}
void *producer(void *argv)//this consumes a queue
{

//  prcmd_t *process;
//  process=(prcmd_t *)malloc(sizeof(prcmd_t));

    printf("producer");
//  while(TRUE)
//  {

//      printf("%d %d\n", process->owner, process->burst_time);

        /* this sleep for seconds */
//      sleep(process->burst_time);




        /* this is where the sleeping from the file will go  */
        //sleep();

        /* acquire the empty lock */
//      sem_wait(&empty);
        /* acquire the mutex lock  */
//      pthread_mutex_lock(&prmutex);

        /* remove an linkedlist from the queue  */
        //remove_queue();

        /* release the mutex lock */
//      pthread_mutex_unlock(&prmutex);
        /* signal empty */
//      sem_post(&empty);

//  }
//  printf("the end of the producer");
}
int get_number_request()
{
    return pending_request;
}
int add_queue(prcmd_t *node)
{
    prcmd_t *temp;
    temp=node;


    pthread_mutex_lock(&prmutex);

    //printf("add_queue\n");


    //printf("%d %d\n", temp->owner, temp->burst_time);

    /* adding a linkedlist to a queue */
    if(pr_head==NULL)//then pr_tail==NULL
    {
        //printf("pr_head==NULL\n");

        temp->next=NULL;
        pr_head=temp;
        pr_tail=temp;
    }
    else
    {
        //printf("pr_head!=NULL\n");
        temp->next=NULL;
        pr_tail->next=temp;
        pr_tail=temp;
    }


    pending_request++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&prmutex);
    //printf("add_queue success\n");
    return(0);
}
void displayQ()
{
    printf("\n\ndisplayQ\n");

    prcmd_t *process=pr_head;

//      printf("%d %d\n", pr_head->owner, pr_head->burst_time);
//      pr_head=pr_head->next;
//      printf("%d %d\n", pr_head->owner, pr_head->burst_time);

    do
    {
        printf("%d %d\n", process->owner, process->burst_time);
        process=process->next;

    }while(process!=NULL);


}
```

Every time I run the code I keep getting a segmentation fault: core dump when my

```
pthread_create(&consumer[i], NULL, (void *)processor, (void *)outLog)
```

is called. Even if I un-comment out the line and switch it with

```
pthread_create(&(consumer[i]), NULL, (void *)processor, (void *)outLog);
```

it still gives me the same exact error and I can't seem to get past it, so I can start working on the rest of the program.

My questions are:

1. Would anybody have any idea on how to figure out why my program keeps give me a segmentation fault: core dump when I run my consumer thread?
2. What would I have to add to my producer function to get that in a consuming mode?

Answer (score 0):

`pthread_create` takes a function pointer as its third parameter. You are passing it an `pthread_t` value. You need to pass it a function pointer, same as you did in your earlier calls.

Any time that you have to add a mysterious cast such as `(void *)`, you really need to make sure that you are doing the right thing, as you are telling the compiler you know what you are doing.

Comment: it gave me a warning about the function not being passed correctly but with the (void *) it didn't give me the warning again

Comment: The warnings are there for a reason. By covering it up with a `(void *)` cast you are saying "I know this doesn't look like a function but trust me that it really is a function"

Comment: yeah it was very confusing to the fact that we have to keep the variables the way the program is stated. All the variable are easy to get switched around. i knew it should have looked like the other pthread_create but i couldn't figure it out till now, thanks!